# Antergos libpthread causes segmentation faults

Tags: linux, glibc, segmentation-fault, antergos

A lot of the programs I use on my machine exit with segfaults. Nearly all programs function normally until being closed, at which point they segfault. So far the only two programs that have not worked because of this issue are VLC and Cinnamon, while many other programs like firefox and chromium are affected, but only segfault on what would have been a normal exit.

This does not seem to be a problem with my RAM. I removed all RAm from my machine and replaced it with one known good stick, but the problem persisted.

On running the affected programs with `gdb`, all seem to return the same trace.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff79af080 in __lll_unlock_elision () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
```

So I am led to believe that the root of the problem is in libpthread. I am currently running glibc version 2.21. Please ask anything more you wish to know, and help if you can. Thank you.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem on my arch install, firefox, midori and evolution crashes, but cli-stuff works and also google-chrome-unstable. Did you do anything specific to your system before this problem occurred?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using a Haswell CPU and thus had to install the updated microcode, wy installing the intel-ucode package.